# If $B \subset \mathbb R^m$ is compact and $x\in \mathbb R^n$ then $\{x\} \times B \subset \mathbb R^{n+m}$ is compact.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, compactness

> If $B \subset \mathbb R^m$ is compact and $x\in \mathbb R^n$ then $\{x\} \times B \subset \mathbb R^{n+m}$ is compact.

If $ \mathcal O$ is open cover of  $\{x\} \times B \subset \mathbb R^{n+m}$ then as $B$ is compact there is finite cover $ \mathcal O'$ of $B$ and hence finite open sets $U$ s.t. $ \{x\} \times U' \subset U \in \mathcal O $ where $U' \in \mathcal O'$.

Is this argument correct?

Comment: "Then as $B$ is compact there is a finite sub-cover". This is problematic, $O$ is a family of open sets in $\mathbb{R}^{n+m}$ and you only know that $B$ is compact with respect to $\mathbb{R}^m$. Basically, the point of the question is that you prove that this quoted sentence really holds.

Comment: **Hint:** If you already know that the continuous image of compact sets is compact again, you don't have to go back to the level of covers and just find a continuous $f\colon \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m+n}$ with $f(B)=\{x\}\times B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Of what cover is $\mathcal O'$ a subcover ?? Let $p: \mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^{n+m}$ be defined by $p(y):=(x,y)$. Then $p$ is continuous. Hence $p^{-1}(G)$ is open for each open set $G \subseteq R^{n+m}$.

Now let $\{O_i: i \in I\}$ be an open cover of $\{x\} \times B$. Then $\{p^{-1}(O_i): i \in I\}$ be an open cover of $B$.

Can you proceed ?